# How can I reduce using extension types in Symfony?

Tags: forms, symfony, controller

In my Controller I am using a lot of extension Types:

```
use Symfony\Component\Form\Extension\Core\Type\TextType;
use Symfony\Component\Form\Extension\Core\Type\ButtonType;
use Symfony\Component\Form\Extension\Core\Type\EmailType;
use Symfony\Component\Form\Extension\Core\Type\HiddenType;
use Symfony\Component\Form\Extension\Core\Type\RepeatedType;
use Symfony\Component\Form\Extension\Core\Type\PasswordType;
use Symfony\Component\Form\Extension\Core\Type\TextareaType;
use Symfony\Component\Form\Extension\Core\Type\SubmitType;
```

Because this takes so much space and is for me unclear, I need to know if there is one line to use just all lines. Something like this:

```
use Symfony\Component\Form\Extension\Core\Type\AllTypes;
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Each of the classes do something specific, and so using them can't be avoided.

However, I do like to drop down the namespace, to help make clear what things are (though it's less necessary here, as they are all suffixed). It does reduce a lot of the bulk in the `use` statements as well.  I do find it quite useful where I may have several classes with the same class name, but in different parts of the codebase - maybe an Entity versus some kind of related service.

```
<?php
use Symfony\Component\Form\Extension\Core\Type; 

->add('hiddenfieldname', Type\HiddenType::class, [...])
->add('password', Type\RepeatedType::class, ....
```

Answer (score 2):

I understand your problem. Seeing too much useles code. It's annoying and it makes developoment slower (and less fun :().

You can use the partial namespace as suggested by @Alister Bulman, but **that would disable automatization by coding standard tools** (like EasyCodingStandard).

I want to keep code style automated, so I solve this **exact problem by using PHPStorm** IDE (it's also free in [EAP versions](https://blog.jetbrains.com/phpstorm/category/eap/)). It nicely collapses the "use" statements:

[image]

Answer (score 0):

As Alister Bulman is a valid solution

Since PHP 7 it's possible to import like this:

```php
use Symfony\Component\Form\Extension\Core\Type\{HiddenType,RepeatedType}; 

->add('hiddenfieldname', HiddenType::class, [...])
->add('password', RepeatedType::class, ....
```

https://www.php.net/manual/en/migration70.new-features.php#migration70.new-features.group-use-declarations